# Como instalar diferentes versões do python no centOS 8?

Tags: python-3.x, centos

Tenho o python3.6 instalado no CentOS Linux release 8.3

```
[fnord@fnord fnord]$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Aug 31  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
12 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 8224 Aug 31  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   25 Jun 24  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   31 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6 -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   17 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   39 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   46 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m-x86_64-config -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m-x86_64-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Mar 16  2021 /usr/bin/python3-config -> /etc/alternatives/python3-config
[fnord@fnord fnord]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[fnord@fnord fnord]$cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011
```

Como eu instalaria o python3.7, python3.8,... no mesmo sistema?

Comment: Questões de configuração de serviços, aplicações e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su], [sf], ou mesmo no https://unix.stackexchange.com/  conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá!

Estou escrevendo essa resposta assumindo que você instalou o python via yum ou dnf.

Para fazer isso, de maneira simplificada, eu pessoalmente criaria **links simbólicos** para cada versão.

Primeiro, baixe o arquivo compactado (tgz) na mão. Use o link https://www.python.org/ftp/python/ para encontrar o arquivo da versão desejada.

Digamos que você queira baixar o 3.8.6, você encontraria em  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/. Então rode os comandos (COMO ROOT):

```
cd /tmp

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tgz

tar -zxvf Python-3.8.6.tgz # descompacte o arquivo

cd Python-3.8.6

./configure

make

make install

make altinstall # esse é o comando mais importante, pois criará a instalação alternativa no /usr/local/bin

# Nesse ponto, o Python 3.8.6 deve estar instalado, basta criar o link simbolico para o diretório /usr/bin

ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8 # SINTAXE: ln -s ARQUIVO_ORIGINAL LINK_SIMBOLICO
```

Após isso, você poderá chamar o comando **python3.8**

O comando **python3** ainda apontará para o Python 3.6 que você tem instalado, para mudar isso deve-se remover o link simbólico do python3 e criar um novo. Espero ter ajudado!